# UFT 12.02 closing issue

Tags: hp-uft

UFT is closing automatically after leaving the system idle for 30 minute, resulting into lost of unsaved script. I did not find any solution to stop this.
Does anybody know to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have UFT's Remote agent running ? that can cause this issue

[image]